# How to change the grace period of a docker image so it's not SIGKILL'ed after 10 seconds?

Tags: docker

When a container is stopped with `docker stop`, `docker` sends `SIGTERM`to the process and waits for 10 seconds as grace period, then if it's still running, [docker sends `SIGKILL` to kill the process](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/).

Let's say that I've a database image that needs more than 10 seconds for grafecully shutdown. So how do I make an image that does not get killed after 10 seconds? Can I increase the grace period time or even let completely skip SIGKILL'ed?

**PS**: Not asking the `-t` parameter of the `docker stop`. I want my image to decide the grace period.

Comment: You can only deal with that _inside_ the container by handling `SIGKILL`. Or just use `docker kill --signal=SIGINT` to send the interrupt without a follow-up kill.